How to have configure _moduleAliases in Express js (Node JS)

If we want any node package? To configure module aliases in package.json.

I need to proper coding related to node path.
For example:-
var file = "../module/filePath.js";
var file2 = "../module/filePath2.js"
Need to have
var file = "@module/filePath"
var file2 = "@module/filePath2"

If this is for any installed packages: why do you want the files of a module? If this is for custom modules, take a look at the answers of this question

You can use module-alias. It lets you define a custom module path:
"_moduleAliases": {
  "@root"      : ".", // Application's root
  "@deep"      : "src/some/very/deep/directory/or/file",
  "@my_module" : "lib/some-file.js",
  "something"  : "src/foo", // Or without @. Actually, it could be any string
}

